How to deal with VAR model when covariance matrix is not positive define?
I am encountering the a couple of complications when trying to apply VAR model over a multivariate time series.
Dataset: the dataset is composed by time series data from several users. For each user, I have a number of features (e.g., F1, F2,...F32), among which one is the target one for forecasting, e.g. F29.
training_set: it is build by sliding time windows of 90 days, producing different blocks for each users, for example, for user i-th
Xi=[<day1,...day89>, <day2,...day90>,...]
Yi=[, ,...]
Python Code (after normalized and made each feature stationary with up to second derivative):
try: model: VAR(training_set) x = model.select_order(maxlags=90) print(x.summary()) except Exception as error: print(error) 
Issue 1: for most of the users, I got: "17 or 31t-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite."
Issue 2: For those users that I am able to run the above code with no errors, when analysing the Results for F29 (the target variable), it turns out that, the p-value <= 0.05 is in relation to different lags for different user, in correspondence to the same feature. For example, for the feature F20, the lag is 10 for user_3 and the lag is 12 for user_4.
In relation to Issue 1, I have searched and it seems that "the error happen when the covariance matrix does not appear numerically to be positive definite.". From this, I understand that there is an opposite signals characterizations in corresponding to the covariance computation.
Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?
In relation to Issue 2: I could not find any useful way to address it. Any idea or help?
